# How seriously did astronomers take the idea of a hollow Phobos?

Tags: mars, history, planetary-science, myth-busting, moons

[Phobos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobos_%28moon%29), the larger moon of Mars, was once theorized to be hollow by [Iosif Shklovsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iosif_Samuilovich_Shklovsky).

Plenty of publications reference the idea (such as this [snippet](http://books.google.com/books?id=DSEDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA101&dq=hollow%20phobos&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b69PUvyOD-LCigLLg4D4CA&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=hollow%20phobos&f=false) from Popular Science), but did anyone take it seriously?  What did astronomers of the day (other than Shklovsky) think of the idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They took it seriously enough to publish a rebuttal to it 3 years later, as is documented in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobos_%28moon%29#Shklovsky.27s_.22Hollow_Phobos.22_hypothesis). As is well known today, there was an error in the mathematics. Specifically, Wikipedia quotes:

> Singer's critique was justified when earlier studies were discovered
>   to have used an overestimated value of 5 cm/yr for the rate of
>   altitude loss, which was later revised to 1.8 cm/yr.

Bottom line is, it was taken quite seriously, but it was discounted rather quickly afterwards.